# Random Code Overkill?

Tags: php

I have some code I am using

```
function genCode ($entropy=1) {
    $truCde = "";
    $indx = 0;
    $leng = 30*$entropy;
    while ($indx < $leng) {
        $code = "";
        $length = 100*$entropy;
        $index = 0;
        while ($index < $length) {
            $code .= rand();
            $index++;
        }
        $index = 0;
        while ($index < $length) {
            $code = sha1($code);
            $index++;
        }
        $truCde .= $code;
        $indx++;
    }
    $finalCode = sha1(rand()) . hash("sha256",$truCde . md5($entropy*rand()));
    $finalCode .= sha1(md5(strlen($finalCode)*$entropy));
    return hash (
        "sha256",
        sha1($finalCode) . sha1(md5($finalCode)) . sha1(sha1($finalCode))
    );
}
```

to generate a random code for e-mail verification. Is there code that takes less time to generate random codes. It takes about 1-2 seconds to run this code, but I am looking to shave .7 seconds off this because the rest of the script will take longer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=random+string+%5Bphp%5D

Comment: Explain to me why you think this is any better than just using the output of rand()?

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look at that. Just wanted to free up some resources.

Comment: @GregS The reasoning behind this is a mystery to me, a previous web developer put this in their code, and I am changing it.

Comment: @macintosh264: To make a random code, use something simple. Take `hash('sha256', rand() . '|' . rand() . '|' . rand())` for example.

Comment: OMG what the heck is this? anther überrandom() entry

Comment: @minitech: This will be no more random.

Comment: Okay, this was massive overkill. sha1(mt_rand()) works fine.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: As you know, there's really no such thing as "more random". It's all "not random" :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's massive overkill. Calling `rand()` repeatedly isn't going to make the code "more random", nor will using random combinations of SHA and MD5 hashes. None of that complexity improves the verification codes.

An improvement that *would* make a difference would be to use `mt_rand()` in preference to `rand()`. The Mersenne Twister pseudo RNG is much stronger than most default `rand()` implementations. The PHP documentation hints that `rand()` may max out at 2<sup>15</sup> meaning you can only generate 32,768 unique verification codes.

Other than that, a single hash call will do.

```
sha1(mt_rand())
```

(You don't even really need to call a hash function as the unpredictability of your codes will come from the random number generator, not the hash function. But hash functions have the nice side effect of creating long hex strings which "look" better.)

Comment: yes the hashes were mostly for the look, I know that does not increase how random the code is.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to generate random strings to test that someone has access to an email address, or something like that, I would throw out that code and use something a lot more straightforward. Something like the following would likely do.

```
function genCode () {
    $chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    $returnValue = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++) {
        $returnValue .= $chars[mt_rand(0, 35)];
    }
    return $returnValue;
}
```

You can hash the return value if you want, but I don't know what the point would be other than to obfuscate the scheme used to come up with the random strings.